# MySQL number of items within the query “OR clause”

Tags: mysql, performance, limit

Is there a limit on the number of items inside query having "OR" statement?
Is the limit on the packet size of the query?

Example:

```
select * from tablename where id = 2 OR id =4 OR ID = 9;
```

Also what is the alternate option?

Comment: You can use in instead of or. As i know the Limit is in the length of the query

Answer (score 2):

A better alternative would be:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id IN(2, 4, 9);
```

As regards the size limit, other databases such as `Oracle` have a limit of `1000`in the number of data you can put inside `IN`, but the limit of `MySQL` depends on the [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) value.

Comment: I've seen 70K numbers in an `IN` clause (in MySQL).

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure I can actually grasp what would this many numbers be needed for 

Comment: The table had over a billion rows; 70K was kinda sluggish, but it did work!  (No, I don't know why they needed such.)

Comment: We are doing purging of useless data. Thats why it is passed as param. I understand there are other solution instead of passing it in query.